# Replicate iOS 8.4 music app search animation

Tags: ios, swift, audio-player

I am making an app with a search button in the nav bar. I would like to replicate the search animation in the music app.

I would like to press search and have the search bar come in from the top, and the table view to fade in.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: I have not tried anything, as I had no idea where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe its pretty simple

It is actually a different view that is sliding down.

So essentially create a view with everything you want on it. Like the textField, the cancel button, etc.

This view when it is created needs to appear above your mainView.

So the y value on your frame will be 0 minus your new view height.

When you are ready for the view to appear use  UIView.animateWithDuration to change your views frame y value to 0

```
  UIView.animateWithDuration(2, delay: 0.0, options:     UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {
        myView.frame = CGRectMake(0, myView.frame.origin.y + myView.frame.height, 100, 100)
        //could also just set the y value to 0 but I included the origin/height part to help you understand

        }, completion: {
            (value: Bool) in


    })
```

Comment: How can I do this if I made the view in a view controller in storyboard?

Comment: So If you are using a UIViewController that has a navigation bar at the top with a search button, you can either create a view over that, then at viewDidLoad, or viewDidLayoutSubviews change where that view will be as I said previously. Or you can create a xib

Comment: Sorry for my questions, I am a beginner. I designed a nib with my search ui. How can I load this onto the screen when I press the search button? I know to make a button pressed event, what code would I put in that function?

Comment: let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "SimpleCustomView", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
        self.addSubview(view);

Comment: feel free to message me any time @MortalMan As JAL stated, stack overflow is designed for very specific questions. As I began programming not too long ago, I understand how hard it can be to find specific questions. Just make sure you're breaking your questions down as much as possible. You'll learn fast

Comment: How can I message you?